# AWS S3 accountId failed to satisfy constraint : Error Code 400 ValidationException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

> Hi all,
>
> I am using AWS S3 SDK 2.2.8 for Image uploading to S3. I have created
>   Bucket in S3 console.
>
> I am using following snippet code to upload a file.

```
String AWS_ACC_ID="XXXX-XXXX-XXX";
String AWS_POOL_ID="us-east-1:XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX";
String AWS_UNAUTH_ROLE="arn:aws:iam:XXXXXXX";
String AWS_AUTH_ROLE="arn:aws:iam:XXXXXXX";   

AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                            context, AWS_ACC_ID,
                            AWS_POOL_ID, AWS_UNAUTH_ROLE,
                            AWS_AUTH_ROLE, Regions.US_EAST_1);        

AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(
                        AwsCredentials.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                        folderPath + file.getName(), file)
                        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

s3Client.putObject(putRequest);
```

> I'm getting following exception:
>
> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected:
>   Value 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX' at 'accountId' failed to satisfy constraint:
>   Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: \d+ (Service:
>   AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   ValidationException; Request ID: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX)
>
> But when I am using old AWS SDK I can able to upload the files to S3.

Answer (score 1):

The account id consists of numbers only. Please remove the dashes.

On the other side, `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` doesn't require your account id any more. It has a simplified constructor which takes only your Cognito pool id and region. See this blog [Sync store access and simplified credentials provider](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx181KO0X8IEH71/Sync-store-access-and-simplified-credentials-provider) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass **null** as **accountId** in the service constructor